# Start the recording using the MIDI piano keyboard?

Tags: midi, garageband

Is it possible, in GarageBand, to start/stop the recording using the midi piano keyboard as it is, for instance with Cubase? My piano is quite far from my mac and I want to start recording from my piano. (I know about the count-down feature)

PS : With cubase, you can define a key on your piano that will be used as command key.

Comment: What version of Cubase do you have?

Comment: Runs on Atari ST 1024 :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have any other buttons available on your keyboard, you can use the [GarageRemote](http://www.muratnkonar.com/otherstuff/garageremote/) software to program them as transport controls for GarageBand. Instructions for M-Audio Axiom series keyboards are available [here](http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/how_to/en398033). I'm not sure about programming an actual keyboard key.